# VB.net Oracle Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update, clob

Ok, i am really in need of finding a way to do this via a string to clob instead of using the update query to to do all.

```
Dim theXMLCode As OracleClob
Dim OracleConnection2 As New OracleConnection()
Dim dr2 As OracleDataReader
Dim holdXML As String = ""

Public Function connectToOracleDB2() As Boolean
    OracleConnection2.ConnectionString = "User Id=" & dbUserId & ";Password=" & dbPassword & ";Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=" & _
                                      "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & dbHost & ")(PORT=" & dbPort & ")))" & _
                                     "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & dbServiceName & ")))"

    Try
        OracleConnection2.Open()
        Return True
    Catch ee As Exception
        OracleConnection2.Close()
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

    Dim strSQL = "UPDATE   CSR.TARGET ces " & _
                 "SET      (STATUS_CODE, COMPLETE_DATE, DATA) = " & _
                    "(SELECT    'ERROR', '', (:XML_DATA) " & _
                    "FROM       CSR.SOURCE C " & _
                    "WHERE      (c.EID = ces.EID) " & _
                    "AND        c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR') " & _
                 "WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT 1 " & _
                 "FROM     CSR.SOURCE C " & _
                 "WHERE    (c.EID = ces.EID) " & _
                 "AND      c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR')"

        Try
            Dim parmData As New OracleParameter

            With parmData
                .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                .OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob
                .ParameterName = "XML_DATA"
                .Value = holdXML
            End With

            OracleCommand2.Parameters.Add(parmData)
            OracleCommand2.CommandText = strSQL
            OracleCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But i get the error:

**ERROR: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.**

On the line:

```
OracleCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Any help would be great to get this thing working :o)

David

Comment: Is holdXML a temp LOB? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cydxhzhz(v=vs.80).aspx for working with Oracle BLOBs in .NET

Comment: holdXML is a string that was populated from the CLOB (blah.value). I need to find a way to convert it back to a CLOB and insert it into the database again. The link you posted doesn't seem to use CLOB?

Comment: There is a CLOB example in the MSDN link. Oracle BLOB/CLOB are pointers, and you cannot update them directly from .NET. Google / Search for the dbms_lob.createtemporary PL/SQL helper.

Comment: @tawman: Cant really find an example dealing with UPDATING a record from a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you could not find an example of creating a temporary lob pointer, here is an example in C# using the Microsoft Enterprise Library from a previous project. This example interfaces with a stored procedure, but is the same approach when using a SQL update and BLOB/CLOB:

```
internal static void Save(Attachments attachment)
    {
        try
        {
            // Microsoft Enterprise Library does not provide support for Oracle BLOB objects
            // The Microsoft Data Provider for Oracle needs to allocate a BLOB pointer in memory first
            // while running in the context of a database transaction. Once the placeholder is allocated,
            // the byte stream is written to the handler and then passed to Oracle to update the database
            //
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring_devl"].ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.CommandText = "declare xx blob; begin dbms_lob.createtemporary(xx, false, 0); :tempblob := xx; end;";
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tempblob", OracleType.Blob)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OracleLob tempLob = (OracleLob)command.Parameters[0].Value;
            tempLob.BeginBatch(OracleLobOpenMode.ReadWrite);
            if (attachment.FileContent != null)
                tempLob.Write(attachment.FileContent, 0, attachment.FileContent.Length);
            tempLob.EndBatch();

            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.CommandText = MC_SAVE_ATTACHMENT;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IN_USER_ID", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = attachment.UserID;
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IN_FILE_CONTENT", OracleType.Blob)).Value = tempLob;
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ERROR_DESC", OracleType.VarChar, 4000)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();

            //Check errors and handle it (log, throw exception etc)
            errors = command.Parameters["error_desc"].Value.ToString();
            HandleExceptions.CheckError(errors);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string errMsg = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- Is the command object associated with a connection object?
- Is the connection open?

Generally, you'd have something like this:

```
Dim conn as new OracleConnection() 'This may have parameters, such as the connection string
OracleCommand2.Connection = conn
conn.Open()
' execute the command
conn.Close()
```

**Important:** This code is messy free-hand code.  I'm not all that familiar with VB syntax anymore, but in C# you'd instantiate the `OracleConnection` object inside the declaration of a `using` statement.  If there's no such thing in VB (though I suspect there is) then you'd wrap it in a try/catch/finally to make sure the connection is properly closed and the object(s) properly disposed.

Comment: Updated the OP with those objects. I've had them but forgot to include them. I don't see how your example fixed the error i am getting, though?

Comment: @StealthRT: Even with the updated code, is the connection being opened anywhere?  It's been a while since I've used ADO.NET objects, but I seem to recall a need to call `.Open()` on the connection object before running a command (and, subsequently, `.Close()` afterward).

Comment: @David: Yes, sorry. Updated my OP with the open part as well.

Comment: @StealthRT: Are you sure this is the code you're actually using?  Does it even compile with code surrounding a function definition like that?  Instead of continuing to edit, why not just copy/paste what you're actually using?  Even still, all that function does is open the connection and return.  It leaves an open connection.  It's not being used to actually _use_ the connection, just open it and leave it open.  Also, the `.Close()` will likely throw an exception of its own if that code is ever reached.  Throwing exceptions from within a `Catch` makes for difficult debugging.

Comment: @David: Sorry, i have all those you said in my code. I just didnt want to post 100+ lines of code and instead just focused on the chunk that was causing the problem. I can connect to the database just fine-thats not a problem. The problems lies with it wanting a CLOB format when i have it passing a string to it.